# Actualizar con Cursor en Oracle

Tags: oracle, cursor

Tengo varias dudas respecto al uso de cursores en ORACLE especialmente para actualizar registros, en varios sitios leí que la declaración del cursor se hace con la parabra CURSOR en el declare, pero en mi trabajo han declarado cursores en Stored Procedures en el apartado AS como sigue:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE sp_xyz(
    v_pcFecInicial IN DATE,
    v_pcFecFinal   IN DATE,
    v_vSuma        IN NUMBER,
    v_vcUsr_actual IN CHAR
    ) AS vcMLista SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
```

De igual forma se utiliza:

```
CURSOR nombre_cursor [ (parámetro [, parámetro, …]) ] IS
SELECT
```

Para declarar el cursor y en mi trabajo utilizamos:

```
open vcMLista for
     SELECT actm_lista.num_entrada , ....
```

¿ Cual de ambas sintaxis es la corecta ?

Comment: Las 2 sintaxis existen y se pueden usar dependiendo de la situación.

Comment: @sstan Podrías explicarme brevemente cuando se usa una y cuando otra, yo estoy haciendo SP con PLSQL.